# React: how to use child FormItem components without getting Warning: validateDOMNesting: <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>

Tags: forms, reactjs, nested-forms

Given the parent component, I am using a child component `DynamicFieldSet` that is a grouping of `FormItems`. But I am receiving the error:

`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>. See CreateTopic > Form > form > ... > DynamicFieldSet > Form > form.`

I have tried to remove the `<Form> </Form>` tags in my child component, but then it is a compile error.

Is there a way I can disable rendering of the child Form view?

**Parent component**

```
class CreateTopic extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
      <div className="create-topic-container">
        <h3>Create an event</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormItem>...</FormItem>
          <FormItem>...</FormItem>
          <FormItem>...</FormItem>
          <FormItem
            {...formItemLayout}
            label="Results"
            style={{ marginBottom: SPACING_FORM_ITEM }}
          >
            {getFieldDecorator('results', {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Results cannot be empty.',
                },
              ],
            })(<DynamicFieldSet
              form={this.props.form}
            />)}
          </FormItem>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**DynamicFieldSet - Child component**

```
export class DynamicFieldSet extends React.Component {
  render() {
    getFieldDecorator('keys', { initialValue: ['0', '1'] });
    const keys = getFieldValue('keys');
    const formItems = keys.map((k, index) => {
      return (
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
          required={false}
          key={k}
        >
          {getFieldDecorator(`results[${k}]`, {
            validateTrigger: ['onChange', 'onBlur'],
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
                whitespace: true,
                message: 'Result name cannot be empty.',
              },
              {
                validator: this.validateLength,
              },
            ],
          })(<Input placeholder={`Result #${index + 1}`} style={{ width: '80%', marginRight: 8 }} />)}
          {keys.length > 2 ? (
            <Icon
              className="dynamic-delete-button"
              type="minus-circle-o"
              disabled={keys.length === 1}
              onClick={() => this.remove(k)}
            />
          ) : null}
        </FormItem>
      );
    });

    return (
      <Form>
        {formItems}
        <FormItem {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}>
          {keys.length < 10 ? (
            <Button type="dashed" onClick={this.add} style={{ width: '80%' }}>
              <Icon type="plus" />Add Result
            </Button>
          ) : null}
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: From which library are you importing Form components ?

Comment: @Dyo I am using `antd` for the Form components

Answer (score 30):

I faced this issue when using `ant design table` and turns out its not ant design which throws the warning. It's the web standards [description](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html)

`"Every form must be enclosed within a FORM element. There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested."`

So, there should not be a form tag inside a form tag.

To solve the issue (in our case), remove the `Form` tag inside the `DynamicFieldSet` "return" and replace with a `div` tag

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ant design has `component` attribute which when set to `false` on nested form, remove nested Form tag and so the error and it will work as if its not nested at all.

Comment: If you set `component` as `false`, please test the working of the code again as it can lead to unexpected behaviours.

Comment: @StarLord what unexpected behaviors could that be?

Answer (score 9):

You can portal a form like this:

```
import Portal from '@material-ui/core/Portal';

const FooComponent = (props) => {
   const portalRef = useRef(null);

   return <>
      <form>
        First form
        <div ref={portalRef} />
      </form>
      <Portal container={portalRef.current}>
        <form>Another form here</form>
      </Portal>
   </>;
}
```

In the example above I use the [react material-ui Portal component](https://material-ui.com/components/portal/). But you can try to implement it with [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) as well

Comment: Thank you! This answer inspires me to use React portal and it works.

Comment: Though it works,  But is not the nested form

Comment: Thanks for pointing out React Portals. Headless UI (the framework I'm using) also has portals. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using MUI, the Box component contains an attribute that identifies them as any native HTML container; form is one of them. E.g:

```
<Box
   xs={6}
   sx={{
       "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" },
       }}
   component="form"
   noValidate
   autoComplete="off"
>
```

In such case, we just need to delete that attribute, it will default to a DIV. The form will continue to work as expected, and the error will disappear off the console.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this is occur bcoz of i declared **`<form>`**  inside another **`<form/>`** tag.

Comment: this is what i need, Thank you!